# The set of prime ideals containing any non-zero proper ideal in a commutative Noetherian ring is finite, by consideration of the topology on $Spec(R)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

In the notes by J.P. May on ‘Associated Prime Ideals’, for $R$ a commutative Noetherian ring and $M$ a non-zero finitely generated
$R$-module, I do not understand the first statement in the proof of the following

> Theorem 0.10. $\mathrm{Ass}(M)$ is a finite subset of $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$, and the minimal elements
> of $\mathrm{Ass}(M)$ and $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$ coincide.
>
> Proof. **The set of prime ideals containing any non-zero proper ideal in
> a commutative Noetherian ring is finite, by consideration of the
> topology on Spec(R)**. But we have a different proof here: the
> finiteness of $\mathrm{Ass}(M)$ follows inductively from the previous two
> propositions...

I am not sure what 'The set of prime ideals containing any non-zero proper ideal in a commutative Noetherian ring' is referring to and how it can be finite since this is for instance the case if the Noetherian ring $R$ has Krull dimension zero (see [$V(I)$ consists of a finite set of points if and only $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ has Krull dimension zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313461/vi-consists-of-a-finite-set-of-points-if-and-only-kx-1-ldots-x-n-i-has)). For instance let $R = k[x_1, .., x_n]$ and $I$ an ideal, then $V(I)$ is the set of prime ideals containing $I$ and $V(I)$ is not necessarily finite; I must be misunderstanding something.

Ref: J.P. May’s notes on ‘Associated Prime Ideals’ [http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/AssoPrimes.pdf](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/MISC/AssoPrimes.pdf)

Comment: The statement in question should read:  "the set of prime ideals minimally containing any non-zero proper ideal in a commutative Noetherian ring is finite."  i.e. for a given ideal $I$, consider the set of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ and if $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal such that $I \subseteq \mathfrak{q} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, then $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{q}$.  In a Noetherian ring, $I$ has a primary decomposition.  The primes minimal over $I$ are a subset the finitely many associated primes of $I$.

Comment: In other words: the notes are slightly incorrect, and your confusion is justified.  But once you make the correction, May's point is that Noetherian rings clearly have Noetherian topological spectrum (meaning descending chains of closed sets stabilize).  Equivalently, a topological space is Noetherian if every subset is compact.  A consequence of this property is that a Noetherian topological space has finitely many irreducible components, which is May's statement about finitely many minimal primes.

Comment: @BadamBaplan that looks like an answer to me, would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: @BadamBaplan This, I totally agree with, and I just recently went over the finiteness of the irreducible components in a Noetherian topological space, corresponding to the minimal primes of $I$. However, how does he obtain that the associated primes of $I$ form a finite set, which includes the minimal primes? I did however see this proof of that from a filtration of M with the ith quotients $\cong R/P_i$ where the $P_i$ are the associated primes of $M = R/I$.